# Get name of CBCentral from an iOS applications using BLE

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have an iOS application that is acting as peripheral using BLE. So, I start advertising and then a computer using a desktop application  is connecting to the mobile.

Is there any way that I can get the "Host name" (CBCentral name)? I get the central instance in the
 
`peripheralManager:central:didSubscribeToCharacteristic:` function but I can get the name of the central.

In general is it possible to get the Central connected to a Peripheral from the Peripheral point of view? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have contacted Apple and they assured me that there is no way to retrieve the name of a `CBCentral` from a `Peripheral` point of view.

Of course, you can add a characteristic to the `Peripheral` dedicated to the `Central` name and let the `Central` write the name on that.